# Make all tds of equal height, when each td contains a div with dynamic content?

Tags: html, css, html-table, equals

I'm trying to make all tds in a table of equal height. I have four cells, each with a width of 25%. Each td will have a div based content, which will be dynamic and varying in length. I cannot change the structure of it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks..!!

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/binita07/kVm7P/1/

## HTML

```
<div class="test">
    <table>
        <td><div>Dummy Content 1</div></td>
        <td><div>Dummy Content 2</div></td>
        <td><div>Dummy Content 1 and will be more</div></td>
        <td><div>Dummy Content 4</div></td>
    </table>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.test{
    width:400px;
    background:#f00;
}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    padding:0;
}
table td{
    width:25%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
    min-height:30px;
}
table td div{
    background:green;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: The tds are already of equal height, it is the divs that aren't. Do you need to use divs? Can you not just put the data into the cells?

Comment: Yes Andy, I need to use the divs inside of td..which is the issue here..I am not able to extend it all the way down.Thanks

Comment: You could remove the background colour from the divs and put it on the tds, using cell-spacing to show the red colour.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simply change `min-height:30px;` to `height:30px;`, indeed- you can actually set it to `height:0px;`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/kVm7P/2/)

You currently have `min-height` set, but this will never work without height being set for the same element as it is a relatively calculated property.

Also, for the child `div` elements you have `height:100%`, however, again, without a specific height being set on the parent `td`, there is no relative reference so it effectively becomes 100% of nothing.

Adding `height:0;` to the parent `td` provides a defined height value for the cell so the div heights can then be calculated relative to *something*, due to layouting this height is forced to expand to fit the child content as opposed to simply 'sticking at zero'.

Comment: Sorry for comment so late, but how to do this work on FF?